# MySQL INSERT not inserting expected value using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to saved image to my server, have look on the code its using php and mysql..i got this error the image location does not appear on my db only the following appears on the table location: ''photos/" it does not save image name.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
// Uploading image file and store it to specific folder & save location into db
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

//storing path to db
$save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location) VALUES ('$location')");
```

Comment: Are you directly running this php file? Show your upload form

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` to see if the image is being received right, also why aren't you making use of those variables?

Comment: how is your form tag? also does "photos" folder have write permission

Comment: print the query to see whats query coming up with and run separately in mysql .. see if its ok .. you will find the error your self ..

Comment: please note that you should not use mysql_* functions anymore as they are unsafe and deprecated ! use PDO of mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your error handling is very bad. Use following code instead;

```
foreach ($_FILES["image"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"][$key];
        $full_path = "photos/" . $name; // be sure path is writable
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $full_path);
        $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location) VALUES ('$full_path')");
    } else {
        die($error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if upload is OK:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]      ["name"]);
    $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

    $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location) VALUES ('$location')");
} else {
    // File not uploaded. Check if you use multipart/form-data in form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I am not giving u the exact answer but it may help u ..
This codes is for uploading image in the database. In DB it will save as a binary as (LONGBLOB)...

Here is the code ...

**html file**

`<form method="POST" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform" id="myform">`
`<input type="file" name="ufile" id="ufile" />`
`<input type="submit" name="upload_ad" value="Create">`

**php file**--*action.php*

`$filesize=$_FILES['ufile']['size'] / 1024;`

`$filetype=$_FILES['ufile']['type'];`

`$filename=$_FILES['ufile']['name'];`

`$tmp_file=$_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'];`

`$content  = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name']));`

`$filename=addslashes($filename);`

`$result = mysql_query("insert into table_name (image) values ('$content')");`